# LibreOffice: Non-numbered chapter

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I wrote a book consisting of several numbered chapters with LibreOffice Writer.

Now I want the first chapter not to be numbered and the second chapter have number 1 (instead of 2 as it is now) and so on for the rest chapters.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I recommend creating a different style for the first chapter's heading, and disable numbering there.